# How to define has_and_belongs_to association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following this video http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised and i implement this also sucessfully. But now i am using namespace.
I have lends_controller inside folder employee inside asset folder.
this is my model of lend controller

```
class Employee::Asset::Lend
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name, type: String
  field :text, type: String
  field :date
  field :asset_tokens
  field :user_id, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assets
  belongs_to :tags
def asset_tokens=(tokens)
 self.asset_ids = Asset.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
 end
end
```

Now i have another model  asset. There i have to define has and belongs to this lend model also I did this

```
class Asset
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :serial_number, type: String
  field :status, type: Integer
  field :tag_tokens
  field :quantity, type: Integer
  validates_presence_of :name 
  validates :serial_number,:uniqueness => true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :employee_asset_lends
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  def self.tokens(query)
   assets = where(name: /#{Regexp.escape(query)}/i)


  end
```

form for lend controller is

```
<%= f.label :asset_tokens, "Assets" %>
  <%= f.text_field :asset_tokens, data: {load: @employee_asset_lend.assets}%><br>
  <%= f.input :date,:input_html => { :class => "dp1"},:label=> "Lend Date"%>
```

inside coffescript file for lend.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#employee_asset_lend_asset_tokens').tokenInput '/assets.json'
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#employee_asset_lend_asset_tokens').data('load')
```

But it gives error `uninitialized constant EmployeeAssetLend from asset views.`
and from lend view it gives error like `undefined method`all_of' for Employee::Asset:Module`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pleaes check the right way to make [HABTM-has_and_belongs_to_many Assosiation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) for more details

Comment: i implement this association in other model. Just i am confuse to apply in my situation because here i am using namespace.

Comment: You can mention the class name along with the namespace  for the same  like `has_and_belongs_to_many :employee_asset_lends, :class_name => 'Employee::Asset::Lend', :dependent => :destroy` .And for table name `self.table_name =  'assets'` and `employee_asset_lends`

Comment: it works but it gives error in lend controller undefined method `all_of' for Employee::Asset:Module... Here i have model asset but it is searchin in  Employee::Asset:Module.. what changes should i do to belongs to asset model? has_and_belongs_to_many :assets

Comment: There is two model one is asset and one is lend. Now asset works fine beacause of your suggestion. Now i get error in lend Model that is in first. here i code  has_and_belongs_to_many :assets . But in error it gives undefined method `all_of' for Employee::Asset:Module. From where it gives error Employee::Asset:Module but class Asset is my module.

Comment: has_and_belongs_to_many :assets inside class Employee::Asset::Lend is it wrong to associate with Asset Model. I am confuse. It is giving me error.

Comment: I got it simply i did  has_and_belongs_to_many :assets,:class_name => 'Asset' and it is ok